# Splitting a Pandas DataFrame based on whether the index name appears in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This should hopefully be a straightforward question but I'm new to Pandas.

I've got a DataFrame called *RawData*, and a list of permissible indexes called *AllowedIndexes*.

What I want to do is **split the DataFrame into two new ones**:

- one DataFrame **only with the indexes that appear** on the ***AllowedIndexes*** list.
- one DataFrame **only with the indexes that don't appear** on the
  ***AllowedIndexes*** list, for data cleaning purposes.

I've provided a simplified version of the actual data I'm using which in reality contains several series.

[[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9MaG.png)

```
import pandas as pd
RawData = pd.DataFrame({'Quality':['#000000', '#FF0000', '#FFFFFF', '#PURRRR','#123Z']}, index = ['Black','Red','White', 'Cat','Blcak'])
AllowedIndexes = ['Black','White','Yellow','Red']
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `.index` takes the index for each row of the RawData dataframe.
2. `.isin()` checks if the element exists in the AllowedIndexes list.

```py
allowed = RawData[(RawData.index.isin(AllowedIndexes))==True]
not_allowed = RawData[(RawData.index.isin(AllowedIndexes))==False]
```

Another way without checking if True, or False:

```py
allowed = RawData[RawData.index.isin(AllowedIndexes)]
not_allowed = RawData[~(RawData.index.isin(AllowedIndexes))]
```

`~` is `not` in pandas.